# Read multiple CSV files in pairs of two them compare each two pair

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a folder with multiple CSV files named like this
*CINinfo_2019-08-08_rev1,CINinfo_2019-08-08_rev2,CINinfo_2019-08-08_rev3, CINinfo_2019-08-08_rev4,* I have about 70 files in one folder my intention is to automate this process so that I can read them automatically in pairs of two then compare for differences in each pair and have the result as one combined table. Currently, I am reading them manually and comparing differences,this is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("CINinfo_2019-08-08_rev1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("CINinfo_2019-08-08_rev2.csv")

import numpy as np
rows,cols=np.where(comparison_values==False)

for item in zip(rows,cols):
    df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]] = '{} --> {}'.format(df1.iloc[item[0], item[1]],df2.iloc[item[0], item[1]])
```

This process is so tedious being that I have other folders with CSV files that I need to read. **Note** how the CSV files are named, all CSV files have the same prefixes (*CINinfo_2019-08-08_*) but suffix in this case name (*rev*) has an incremental number from 1 to 70. The way I need this to read files in pairs is in format *1 and 2*, *2 and 3,* *3 and 4* going on. In this case I compare pairs like this, *CINinfo_2019-08-08_rev1 and CINinfo_2019-08-08_rev2* then *CINinfo_2019-08-08_rev2 nd CINinfo_2019-08-08_rev3* going like that, How can I automate the reading of this files in pairs then compare for differences in each pair of them and have one joined table?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
import os, re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# your directory path here
path = r'path'

# get all files 
file_, pat = [], re.compile('.csv')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    file_ = [os.path.join(root, f) for f in files if pat.search(f)]

# you may want to filter here, this line is just an example
# filter for all csv files containing 'rev'
file_ = [f for f in file_ if 'rev' in f]

# loop through the files of interest
for (idx, ff) in enumerate(file_[1:]):
    df1 = pd.read_csv(ff)
    df2 = pd.read_csv(file_[idx])

    rows, cols = np.where(comparison_values==False)
    for item in zip(rows,cols):
        # do calculation
```

This answer is not all inclusive, but hopefully will give you a possible approach. You may need to adjust filtering, or possibly sort. I have not shown how to add the results to a final table, but the best thing to do is create a DataFrame `temp` and assign the values from the file pairs to it and then use `pd.concat` to add to a final DataFrame that wil contain all results.

Comment: could you please assist with putting the result on the final table or simply if I can be able to view each pair compared. Thank you